# SPF configuration question

Tags: domain-name-system, spf

I understand the basics to setting up an SPF record in my zone files, on my DNS.
And for the most part it seems easy enough to configure.
However, I've been constantly testing my postfix server with simple PHP scripts, and sending emails to myself via smtp.

I've configured the spf to allow for my mail servers to be permitted. I've included the ip addresses, and now I've changed to domain names.

Here's what I've got:

```
@  IN TXT "v=spf1 a mx include:_spf.google.com a:subdomain.anothersite.com ~all"
```

When I relay thru google's mail servers I always get a neutral response:

---

"Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 209.85.210.41 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of mypersonalsite.com) client-ip=209.85.210.41"

"Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=neutral (google.com: 209.85.210.41 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of mypersonalsite.com) smtp.mail=me@mypersonalsite.com"

---

I get that from the "Show Original" option, inside my gmail account.
It may be nothing, but I've been expecting something other than "is neither permitted nor denied by best guess", from google.

I see the same thing with qualified companies, with correct spf settings.  And then I see places with a "pass".

Has anyone had any luck moving from "neutral" to "pass"?

Comment: Sure. Always. Test your settings online http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html But if you want us to check, then we need the concrete SPF and domain.

Comment: +1 for request for actual data.  Why obscure this?  It's in the DNS, which is about as publicly-visible as you get.  Just tell us the domain so we can try to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not recognizing the `TXT` record as valid SPF because of a typo, and falling back to the default of `?all`.

Change `v=sfp1` to `v=spf1`:

```
@  IN TXT "v=spf1 a mx include:_spf.google.com a:subdomain.anothersite.com ~all"
```

Comment: +1 copy-n-paste is your friend

Comment: The typo was only on here, not in the zone file. I didn't want to include the entire thing, and ended up typing too fast.

Comment: @user271619 Google's using "best guess" records, which means that they're either not able to retrieve, or not able to parse, your record.  What do you get from `nslookup -querytype=txt maildomain.com`?